# How can I restrict data use on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, parental-controls

I need to know if there is an app for iPhone 5 that would control the data (or lock it down entirely)?
Also need to control who is called and what callers can be received.

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer because it only partially addresses your question.  Most carriers have parental controls available on the account.  Look into those first because they're implemented at the account level instead of at the iPhone.  This gives you more control and visibility because it affects the data before it gets to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

The full information on use restrictions in iOS is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304). It doesn't include the ability to restrict the use of phone calls or data, but you can restrict apps like Safari that use the data. Third-party apps are not permitted to modify fundamental iOS functionality like this.

Comment: You should not just provide a link but provide a summary of the info here so the answer stands alone

Comment: @Mark I did provide a summary. The exact list of apps that can be restricted is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: The summary would be go to page X and then choose which apps are allowed data